# Where I can find the appWizard that can generate C++ application

Tags: c++, wizard

I have an project to modify. This project was create with AppWizard many years ago. This generated weird code when I open it with visual studio 8. I would like to modify the interface. Can I find a free AppWizard.

Thanks,

Comment: can you explain the "Weird" code?  Are you using the "Free" version of visual studio?  If so, MFC is not supported and I think the GUI tools are not available.  What does your app do and what kind of project is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using Visual Studio 6.0 it worked.